# How to do a binomial expansion with either plus or minus sign

Tags: fortran

Is there a way to expand a binomial expression with either a plus or minus sign between the two terms? e.g. (x+y)^3 ; (x-y)^5

I did

```
program binom

implicit none
integer :: nth = 5, i, pow1, pow2, comb
character(100) :: strpow1, strpow2, comb1, var1='x', var2='y'

do i=0, nth
    pow1=(nth-i)
    pow2=(i)
    write(strpow1,'(i10)') pow1
    write(strpow2,'(i10)') pow2
    comb=cnr(nth,i) 
    write(comb1,'(i10)') comb 
    write(*,'(7a)') comb1, var1,"^",strpow1,var2,"^",strpow2
end do

contains
  integer function cnr(n,r)     
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: n,r   
    integer :: i, ans            
    integer :: large, small    

    if ((n-r) > r) then
       large = n - r
       small = r
    else
       large = r
       small = n - r
    end if

    ans = 1
   
    do i = large+1, n
       ans = ans*i
    end do

    do i = 2, small
       ans = ans/i
    end do

    cnr = ans
  end function cnr
 
end program binom
```

It wasn't the right code at all. Btw, the code inside the function was given to us.

Comment: Hint x-y=x+(-y)

Comment: I think I worked things out a little bit but I don't know why the string length in this line write(*,'(7a)') comb1, var1,"^",strpow1,var2,"^",strpow2 is 100. I know that I set the character length to 100 but when I tried to trim, trim doesn't work.

Comment: Trim does work, I just didn't put it where it's supposed to be in. I got the binomial expansion now. Thanks for the help, Ian.

Comment: Hint #2. (x + (-1**i * Y))